# Get shipment collection from order id

Tags: magento2, sales-order, shipment

Normally you can get order shipment colletion like this from order:

```
$order->getShipmentsCollection();
```

but i'd like to retrieve the collection of shipments using order id, and i want to sort it by entity_id, so it will become like this:

```
$shipmentCollections = $this->shipmentModel->create()
                    ->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("order_id",$orderId)->setOrder('entity_id','DESC');
```

Answer (score 1):

To get shipments by order ID you can use `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\CollectionFactory`:

```
protected $_shipmentCollection;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\CollectionFactory $shipmentCollection,
) {
    $this->_shipmentCollection = $shipmentCollection;
}

public function getShipmentsByOrderId($order_id) {
    $shipments = $this->_shipmentCollection->create()->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $order_id)->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC');

    // Use $shipment->getItems() to iterate over results
}
```